# My encrypt and decrypt function is not working when passing text with numeric data

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

when i am passing normal alphabet to my encrypt and decrypt function then it is working as expected but when i am passing alphanumeric text to encrypt and decrypt function then it is not working.

say when i pass encrypt("test1") or decrypt("test1") then it is not working. specially decrypt not working with alphanumeric case.

i want to restructure my encrypt and decrypt function as a result whatever value i pass the function can work. suppose i may pass alpha numeric data with special character. so plerase see the code and come with rectified version.

a small wrapper around encrypt/decrypt

```
   private string encrypt(string message)
    {
        EncryptClass.EncryptClass ec = new EncryptClass.EncryptClass();
        string encryStr = ec.custEncrypt(message);
        return encryStr;
    }

    private string decrypt(string message)
    {
        EncryptClass.EncryptClass ec = new EncryptClass.EncryptClass();
        string decryptStr = message;
        return ec.custDecrypt(decryptStr);
    }
```

full code for encrypt ans decrypt

```
public class EncryptClass
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider rj;
    byte[] key = new byte[] { 11, 9, 3, 4, 1, 8, 12, 7 };
    byte[] IV = new byte[] { 1, 8, 7, 16, 1, 9, 0, 3 };
    public EncryptClass()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
        rj = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    }

    // for encryption
    public string custEncrypt(string message)
    {
        //create a memory stream
        MemoryStream ciphertextmem = new MemoryStream();
        //create a crypto stream in write mode
        CryptoStream crystm = new CryptoStream(ciphertextmem, rj.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        //Encode the passed plain text string into Unicode byte stream
        Byte[] plaintextbyte = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(message);
        //Write the plaintext byte stream to CryptoStream
        crystm.Write(plaintextbyte, 0, plaintextbyte.Length);
        //don't forget to close the stream
        crystm.Close();
        //Extract the ciphertext byte stream and close the MemoryStream
        Byte[] ciphertextbyte = ciphertextmem.ToArray();
        ciphertextmem.Close();
        //Encode the ciphertext byte into Unicode string
        string ciphertext = new UnicodeEncoding().GetString(ciphertextbyte);
        return ciphertext;
        //return "encry " + message;


    }

    // for decryption
    public string custDecrypt(string message)
    {
        //Create a memory stream from which CryptoStream will read the cipher text
        MemoryStream ciphertextmem = new MemoryStream(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(message));

        //Create a CryptoStream in Read Mode; initialise with the Rijndael's Decryptor ICryptoTransform
        CryptoStream crystm = new CryptoStream(ciphertextmem, rj.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        //Create a temporary memory stream to which we will copy the 
        //plaintext byte array from CryptoStream

        MemoryStream plaintextmem = new MemoryStream();
        do
        {
            //Create a byte array into which we will read the plaintext 
            //from CryptoStream
            Byte[] buf = new Byte[100];

            //read the plaintext from CryptoStream
            int actualbytesread = crystm.Read(buf, 0, 100);

            //if we have reached the end of stream quit the loop
            if (0 == actualbytesread)
                break;

            //copy the plaintext byte array to MemoryStream
            plaintextmem.Write(buf, 0, actualbytesread);

        } while (true);

        //don't forget to close the streams
        crystm.Close();
        ciphertextmem.Close();

        //Extract the plaintext byte stream and close the MemoryStream
        Byte[] plaintextbyte = plaintextmem.ToArray();
        plaintextmem.Close();

        //Encode the plaintext byte into Unicode string
        string plaintext = new UnicodeEncoding().GetString(plaintextbyte);

        return plaintext;

        //return "decry "+ message;
    }
}
```

please see my code and rectified area as a result it should work **if i pass only text or if i pass text with numeric data or alphanumeric with special character.**

looking for help.

Comment: Please clarify 'not working', do you have an Exception message?

Comment: yes was getting some error

Comment: I cant get it to work with just text; from just a brief glance there are several things wrong.  what is the "some error"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much simpler ways to do that, and there are several serious flaws in your implementation:

1. Using the same IV and a static key is not much protection at all
2. The result cannot be expressed as a text string, which may be the core problem making the round trip
3. You *can* use a `CryptoStream` but unless you are outputting to a stream, it just over complicates matters.

I tried to just mend your code, but in the end it was easier to just start fresh:

```
public class EncryptClass
{
    const int hashCount = 21569;

    public static string EncryptString(string message, string pass)
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rij.GenerateIV();
            rij.Key = HashPassword(pass);

            using (ICryptoTransform cryptor = rij.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                var buff = cryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                // concat to the IV for the other side
                // crypto data is binary - use Base64 for text encoding
                return Convert.ToBase64String(rij.IV.Concat(buff).ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] HashPassword(string thePW)
    {
        // originally from RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetRandomBytes
        byte[] salt = new byte[] { 96, 248, 204, 72, 177, 214, 251, 82, 174, 
                        90, 82, 90, 111, 76, 146, 172 };

        using (var hasher = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(thePW, salt, hashCount))
        {
            return hasher.GetBytes(32);
        }
    }
```

This uses `RijndaelManaged` as the crypto provider.  As you can see, it is pretty simple.  Some key points:

- The methods are static
- A new IV is generated each time.
- The resulting crypto output is concatenated to the IV, so it will be available to the Decryptor.  If you were encrypting to a file stream, write them IV bytes to the naked `FileStream`
- This version hashes the password using PBKDF, some initially random salt and a large number of iterations
- Since it is just a string, `TransformFinalBlock` is all you need to encrypt it
- The result is encoded as Base64

I'm not sure why you used Unicode encoding, so I left that in.  Decrypting is just as easy:

```
public static string DecryptString(string crypted, string pass)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(crypted);
    using (RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        int size = (int)(rij.BlockSize / 8);
        byte[] iv = new byte[size];

        // copy the iv to the array
        Array.Copy(data, 0, iv, 0, size);

        rij.IV = iv;
        rij.Key = HashPassword(pass);

        using (ICryptoTransform cryptor = rij.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            var buff = cryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, size, data.Length - size);
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buff);
        }
    }
}
```

After converting the Base64 string back to bytes, the IV is fetched from the byte array, and `TransformFinalBlock` is given the offsets into the array to account for the IV.  Usage and testing:

```
string msg = "This is some text 123 1 87  45";

string crypto = EncryptClass.EncryptString(msg, "I Like Pi");
Console.WriteLine(crypto);
string retVal = EncryptClass.DecryptString(crypto, "I Like Pi");
Console.WriteLine(retVal);
```

Results:

> mIfpIkTVC7mI5R1hlIIpVs63N/j4LN+p2pGPuo90eEPWvW+sqSiBIDjto1+E1p0umdI1hDnkxa2droAbuAFwPzuNK3gABrFjsNpi6FXwGOw=
>
> This is some text 123 1 87  45

The top line is the Base64 form of the encrypted data; the second is the decryption output.

Comment: Is it base64 encryption ? If yes the problem is one can reverse base64 very easily. Please share your view. Thanks and happy new year to you.

Comment: No, the encryption is Rijndael the output cannot be stored as a string/text though which as I explained was part of the problem with what you had originally.  So, the result is encoded to Base64

Comment: What is relations between rijndael and base64? What is IV u talked about here.

Comment: Nope.  The salt is clearly defined in `HashPassword`

Comment: what do u mean by IV?

Comment: why HashPassword function is required here?

Comment: `I Like Pi` is the password.  The password is hashed with some salt to make the encryption key: `rij.Key = HashPassword(pass);`.  My IV serves the same exact purpose as the IV in your original code. Hashing the password is needed so it is not easy to guess the password.  Sorry, but I cannot teach you the basics of crypto in comments; it is a broad and precise area.  Please upvote the answer since it helped